# How to assign SUPER permissions to a specific company?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-business-central

I'm trying to attach the debugger to a Business Central Cloud but I get the following error:

[image]

Basically it's saying that I don't have permissions for one of the 2 companies that exist in the environment

So I go to the user permissions and it looks like this:

User Groups:

[image]

User Permissions:

[image]

When I try to give SUPER role for that company I get this error:

[image]

If I try to just leave the company column as blank it will throw the same error

What can I check to grant permissions to that company or how can I know which is the administrator user that can do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first user created in the system is the user who can manage the permissions and give SUPER to any other user